# Text under pmatrix in align environment

Tags: amsmath, matrices, vector

I'm new here and I hope I don't do anything wrong.
I googled and cant somehow find a way to get text under my vectors. Heres my code:

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{n} 
\end{pmatrix}

\xrightarrow{\texttt{\color{red}LDA}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{k}
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{with $n < k$}
\end{align*}
```

I would like to have something like that:

```
    / \
   |   |
   |   |
    \ /
   Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use stacks.  With `\useanchorwidth` set to `T`rue, the text does not affect the underlying math spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\stackunder{$\begin{pmatrix} 
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{n} 
\end{pmatrix}$}{Text\strut}
%
\xrightarrow{\texttt{\color{red}LDA}} 
\stackunder{$\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{k}
\end{pmatrix}$}{Help me\strut} \qquad \text{with $n < k$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Somehow it doesn't work for me: ! Undefined control sequence. <argument>  \stackunder {$\begin {pmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ \vdots \\ x_{n}...

Comment: @Werryl Did you include the `stackengine` package in your preamble?

Comment: It worked now. Somehow the package that I loaded in the praeamble does not work in a file that I included via \input{}. I merged it now into one file and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use a simple `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}[t]{c}
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        x_{1} \\
        x_{2} \\
        \vdots \\
        x_{n} 
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    \mathclap{\text{\strut Some Text}}
\end{array}
%   
    \xrightarrow{\textcolor{red}{LDA}} 
%   
  \begin{array}[t]{c}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_{1} \\
        x_{2} \\
        \vdots \\
        x_{k}
    \end{pmatrix} \\ 
    \mathclap{\text{\strut again some text}}
  \end{array}
%  
\text{with $n < k$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]